# When is a process polled by Contiki kernel if its needspoll variable has been set using process_poll(&process)

Tags: c, serial-port, contiki

I do not understand the meaning of the function "process_poll(&serial_line_process); " which is used in core/dev/serial-line.c file of Contiki OS.  i've read on the [wiki pages](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Processes) that it sets the needspoll variable in the process control block enabling the kernel to poll this process when an interrupt occurs. If someone could shed light on how and when this process gets called, i would be highly obliged.

I came across this problem while trying to read serial input using contiki specific mechanism as explained on the wiki pages. The characters are read from the serial port and I verified that program control reached process_poll( &serial_line_process) ; statement in function int serial_line_input_byte(unsigned char c); in file serial-line.c. This has been set as a callback for the serial input drivers for the platform. But after that nothing happened. It seems that the process serial_input_process initially executed PROCESS_YIELD(); statement and hasn't been called since then. The following is the code for the process i used for testing.

```
 #include "contiki.h"
 #include "dev/serial-line.h"
 #include <stdio.h>

 PROCESS(test_serial, "Serial line test process");
 AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&test_serial);

 PROCESS_THREAD(test_serial, ev, data)
 {
   PROCESS_BEGIN();

   for(;;) {
     PROCESS_YIELD();
     if(ev == serial_line_event_message) {
       printf("received line: %s\n", (char *)data);
     }
   }
   PROCESS_END();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `process_poll()` will invoke your pollhandler, eg

```
PROCESS_POLLHANDLER(pollhandler());
```

The process will be sent the PROCESS_EVENT_POLL event, so if you prefer you can wait for it like this:

```
PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(ev == PROCESS_EVENT_POLL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maneesh, the problem is not with `process_poll` function. After struggling for weeks with this problem, I found that the problem is that `process_init` needs to be called before `serial_line_init` function in `main()`. Otherwise the `serial_line_process` will not be added in the `process_list` and calling `process_poll` will be useless.